# Selenium in Python: calling WebElement.is_displayed() or get_attribute() affects page behaviour

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium in Python to check notifications on a website. I'm finding that if I breakpoint after loading the page and click on the notifications icon, everything works fine. But if I breakpoint after a few lines which call find_element, is_displayed, and is_enabled, the notifications no longer load. I don't feel like updating the screenshots I already took, but I narrowed it down to the bubbleElement.is_displayed() call. Before that call it works, and after the call it doesn't.

I'm curious as to why is_displayed causes side effects and also looking for a solution or workaround to see if the element is visible. In trying to work around it, I've found that calling get_attribute('innerText') causes the same issue. I've included screenshots of the code and results below.

[Breakpoint before additional selenium calls.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8HVM.png)

[Notifications working correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX9Jl.png)

[Breakpoint after additional selenium calls.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuV3F.png)

[Notifications not working correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Zhm.png)

**Edit:** current workaround is just to click it and catch the ElementNotInteractableException if it fails, but I'm still interested in why this happens and if there's a cleaner solution.